# Can I control serialization of certain fields using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

Can I control serialization of certain fields using XmlSerializer in c#? Fox example an property named "Type"(string) to be serialized as something else instead of string.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can Control what gets serialize based on [Serializable] attribute so with a Class for example you can choose to have the whole class Serialized or just certain properties for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control a few things via [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) / [`XmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) annotations -- the name of the element, whether it is an attribute or full XML element, etc.  However, you can't change the type directly.  If you need to support any type of complex serialization scheme, `XmlSerializer` is not a good choice due to its many limitations.  You're better off using `DataContractSerializer` (see ["Using Data Contracts"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) in the WCF documentation) or maybe even writing it yourself.

If you just want to change the XML type of the resulting serialized data (e.g. using a custom XML type or namespace), you *can* do that with the [`XmlType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) attribute, but that will only work for types you have declared and not primitive CLR types (e.g. you can't make a string into an integer or another more complex type).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [IXmlSerializable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

You can't control typing just using Attributes.  You have to roll your own code for serialize/unserialize the class.  That interface allows you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can control what you want to serialize through XMLIgnore attribue.This will not serialize the property decorated with this attribute.

YOu can also use XMLType to manager how a type is serialized by XML serializer but that doesnt mean in anyway that you can directly effect the CLR type.

You cant change CLR types using serialization.